# Hyperledger Fabric registerChaincodeEvent() method not getting the event from chaincode

Tags: node.js, go, events, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After deploying my chaincode successfully and being able to perform some get from its data (all data returned are correct), I am not able to check if an event is emitted.
The function inside `Invoke()` is `queryAllMachines()` and if I call just this function it returns a set of machines (the set of machine insert in the method InitLedger())

I follow the documentation and my chaincode (in go) should emit an event in this code line inside its `queryAllMachines()` function:

```
func (s *testContract) queryAllMachines(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
    fmt.Println("inside queryAllMachines\n")
    ...
    err = APIstub.SetEvent("evtsender", []byte("adadsads"))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("event not set")
    }
    fmt.Printf("No errors\n")
}
```

This code always prints "no errors", so I suppose the events is emitted rightly.

Then in my .js file for query i have the request:

```
let request = {
        chaincodeId: 'oraclize-test-integration',
        fcn: 'queryAllMachines',
        args: [''],
        txId: tx_object
    };
```

Then this is the part of my .js file where I have the problem and where I want to launch `registerChaincodeEvent()`:

```
let event_monitor = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let regid = null;
        let handle = setTimeout(() => {
            if (regid) {
                // might need to do the clean up this listener
                channel_event_hub.unregisterChaincodeEvent(regid);
                console.log('Timeout - Failed to receive the chaincode event');
            }
            reject(new Error('Timed out waiting for chaincode event'));
        }, 20000);

        regid = channel_event_hub.registerChaincodeEvent('oraclize-test-integration', 'evtsender',
            (event, block_num, txnid, status) => {
                // This callback will be called when there is a chaincode event name
                // within a block that will match on the second parameter in the registration
                // from the chaincode with the ID of the first parameter.
                console.log('Successfully got a chaincode event with transid:' + txnid + ' with status:' + status);

                // might be good to store the block number to be able to resume if offline
                storeBlockNumForLater(block_num);

                // to see the event payload, the channel_event_hub must be connected(true)
                let event_payload = event.payload.toString('utf8');
                if (event_payload.indexOf('CHAINCODE') > -1) {
                    clearTimeout(handle);
                    // Chaincode event listeners are meant to run continuously
                    // Therefore the default to automatically unregister is false
                    // So in this case we want to shutdown the event listener once
                    // we see the event with the correct payload
                    channel_event_hub.unregisterChaincodeEvent(regid);
                    console.log('Successfully received the chaincode event on block number ' + block_num);
                    resolve('RECEIVED');
                } else {
                    console.log('Successfully got chaincode event ... just not the one we are looking for on block number ' + block_num);
                }
            }, (error) => {
                clearTimeout(handle);
                console.log('Failed to receive the chaincode event ::' + error);
                reject(error);
            }
            // no options specified
            // startBlock will default to latest
            // endBlock will default to MAX
            // unregister will default to false
            // disconnect will default to false
        );
    });

    // build the promise to send the proposals to the orderer
    let send_trans = channel.sendTransaction({
        proposalResponses: query_responses[0],
        proposal: query_responses[1]
    });

    // now that we have two promises all set to go... execute them
    return Promise.all([event_monitor, send_trans]);
```

The error that appears is:

> Timeout - Failed to receive the chaincode event (node:9180)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 3): Error: Timed out waiting for chaincode event
>   (node:9180) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>   are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with anon-zero exit code.

So the functions times out in this part of the code, even if I launch another .js file that execute successfully the call to `queryAllMachines()` function:

```
let handle = setTimeout(() => {
            if (regid) {
                // might need to do the clean up this listener
                channel_event_hub.unregisterChaincodeEvent(regid);
                console.log('Timeout - Failed to receive the chaincode event');
            }
            reject(new Error('Timed out waiting for chaincode event'));
        }, 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest high-level API makes it simple,

```
        const listener = await contract.addContractListener('asset creation-listener', 'saveAsset123456789', (err, event, blockNumber, transactionId, status) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`The event payload is :${event.payload}`)
            console.log(`Block Number: ${blockNumber} Transaction ID: ${transactionId} Status: ${status}`);
        })
```

check [this](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-listening-to-events.html) doc for more information